# Why is a reference called "shared"?

Tags: reference, rust, terminology

This is my minimal reproducible code ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ef2911c44ac19810b1bba0d4b0bf856d)):

```
struct MyStruct {
    my_string: String,
}

fn accepts_string(my_string: String) {
    println!("my_string: {}", my_string)
}

fn accepts_struct_reference(my_struct: &MyStruct) {
    accepts_string(my_struct.my_string);
}

fn main() {
    let my_struct = MyStruct {
        my_string: String::from("hi"),
    };
    accepts_struct_reference(&my_struct);
}
```

which produces:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `my_struct.my_string` which is behind a shared reference
  --> src/main.rs:10:20
   |
10 |     accepts_string(my_struct.my_string);
   |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ move occurs because `my_struct.my_string` has type `std::string::String`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

I believe I understand why this error occurs: `accepts_string` tries to take the string away from the struct.

Why is that reference called a `shared` reference? Shared with whom? Does that adjective mean that there are non-shared references? If yes, what do they look like?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is another way to distinguish mutable and immutable references.

In Rust, there is a clear distinction: the data can be *either* sharable (even if they're not shared currently), *or* directly mutable, **but not both at once**. This is achieved by having two types of references:

- *shared*, or *immutable* ones, which can be copied but cannot be used to directly mutate data;
- *unique*, or *mutable* ones, which cannot be copied (and this is UB, if you do this somehow), but can be used to mutate the data.

Note the "directly mutable" bit. Of course, it's *sometimes* possible to modify data through shared reference - if the data itself allows it; this is so-called *internal mutability*, based on multiple types like `Cell` or `Mutex`, which all internally use `UnsafeCell` - the only type explicitly allowed to be mutated behind shared reference.

More info might be found here: https://limpet.net/mbrubeck/2019/02/07/rust-a-unique-perspective.html

Comment: Thanks! That's almost exactly the answer I received in the Rust discord chat. The only difference, they called `exclusive` what you call `unique`. But these fairly are just synonyms. Also, thanks for the link to a great article!

Comment: @NurbolAlpysbayev: In the year prior to 1.0, there was actually an impetus to rename `&mut` to `&uniq` to emphasize that given the existence of internal mutability what mattered was shared vs unique/exclusive, and that immutable/mutable were misnomers. It was rejected because although pedantically correct, it seemed easier to teach immutable/mutable at the beginning, and people would just discover the actual nitty gritty reality if they stuck with the language. I guess it means you've passed the beginner stage, congratz!

Comment: @MatthieuM. Thank you for the insight, that was entertaining to read. I am glad that they've made this decision, because `uniq` would make me, a beginner, cringed and confused. Oh and good to head that I am no longer a beginner, it feels like I've passed some initiation procedure :D